# Sonarqube 6 issues view shows limited results

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

Sonarqube issues view shows only violations against top 15 rules, Is there a way I could see a list of all rules with issues count.

Both ProjectIssueFilter and IssueFilter show only 15 issues in the view. The filter shows this message "**Only the first 15 results are displayed**". Is there a way to see the complete list?

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible to see more rules (writing at the time of SonarQube 6.1). It is planned to be improved. You can vote and follow the ticket https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6400.

Answer (score 0):

A trick I use to see more rules:

- filter on Directory and/or Files.
- You can sometimes see more rules, which was previously not visible.
- Select the previously hidden rule(s).
- Remove the filter on Directory and/or Files
- You will still see the hidden rules with all the occurrences

It's a bit a pain, but it works...